# Django Templates [Beginner]

Tags: django

I'm a complete noob with Django and have been googling for a while but I can't figure out what a portion of this template is doing.

https://github.com/oppian/oppian/blob/master/oppianproj/templates/about.html

```
{% load set_vars_from_json %}   
{% set_vars_from_json_block %}
    { "menu":
      [{"name":"About", "url":"{% url about %}"},
       {"name":"People", "url":"{% url people %}"},
       {"name":"Labs", "url":"{% url labs %}"},
       {"name":"Blog", "url":"{% url blog %}"},
       {"name":"Contact", "url":"{% url contact %}"}
      ]}   
{% end_set_vars_from_json_block %}
```

Why does the developer, load and set variables from a json_block? What advantage does this provide? My guess is that the menu urls are dynamically changed?

Simple Side Question:
For site content, such as the information within

```
<p>....</p>
```

, does this belong in templates or should I handle this as static data using a module?

EDIT: Or for the side question, do I just create a model for each page if I intend to store large paragraphs of static data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the following [URL](https://github.com/oppian/oppian/blob/master/oppianproj/apps/oppianapp/templatetags/set_vars_from_json.py)

`set_vars_from_json_block` is a template tag

```
{ "menu":
      [{"name":"About", "url":"{% url about %}"},
       {"name":"People", "url":"{% url people %}"},
       {"name":"Labs", "url":"{% url labs %}"},
       {"name":"Blog", "url":"{% url blog %}"},
       {"name":"Contact", "url":"{% url contact %}"}
      ]}
```

This loads the json snippet, and in the templatetag, it parses for `end_set_vars_from_json_block` to make it a block based implementation.

You could just have one model to save all by specifying "type". Check out [Django Picklefield](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield/)